# Show that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a union of closed sets containing no nonempty open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

From Abbott's 'Understanding Analysis':

[image]

This exercise is given before Baire's theorem.

Comment: Well, I'd say the comment on Baire's Category Theorem is *very* relevant, as with that theorem your question is completely trivial...

Comment: A consequence of Baire's category theorem is that it is impossible to write a complete metric space $X$ as a countable union of closed set containing no nonempty open sets. Here you just take $X=\mathbb{R}$. Are you looking for a proof of this exercise without using the Baire's category theorem?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks, changed it. I haven't read into Baire's theorem yet because I want to solve this first.

Comment: As a hint try to consider what the statement "containing no nonempty closed intervals" means for what types of closed sets you have.

Comment: Maybe Abbott put this exercise there so that the student will think about it (and perhaps fail to solve it), and then realize how great Baire's theorem is when it comes later?

Comment: @GEdgar I considered that, but I still posted because there's always the possibility I'm missing something obvious that makes it a simple problem.

Comment: @An.Ditlev I am considering that, and intuitively it seems to me that a union of (closed) sets with that property can itself not contain a nonempty open interval (I could be wrong about this) which obviously means it can not be equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Have you perhaps seen Cantor's original argument for the uncountability of $\mathbb R$, not the argument that diagonalizes decimal expansions but the one that produces a shrinking sequence of intervals? If so, then this argument can be fairly easily modified to solve the present exercise (and then another fairly easy modification proves the full Baire category theorem, with arbitrary complete metric spaces in place of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: It is not unusual (although not very common in introductory texts) for an author to include an exercise that is a special case of a general theorem $before$ the theorem is introduced.  Readers who solve it will understand the theorem more readily.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the Nested Interval Theorem to show it.
Because $F_n$ has no nonempty open intervals, it also has no nonempty closed intervals (except for singletons [a,a]).
Let $G_n = F_n^c$. Because $F_n$ is closed, $G_n$ is open.
Because $F_1$ has no nonempty open intervals, $\exists x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1 \in G_1$. Because $G_1$ is open, $\exists \epsilon_1 > 0$ such that $V_{\epsilon_1}(x_1) \subseteq G_1$. Because $V_{\epsilon_1}(x_1)$ is an open interval, it can be expressed as $(x_1 - \epsilon_1 , x_1 + \epsilon_1)$. Then define $I_1 = [x_1 - \frac{\epsilon_1}{2}, x_1 + \frac{\epsilon_1}{2}]$. Because $F_2$ has no nonempty open intervals, $\exists x_2 \in I_1$ such that $x_2 \in G_2$. Because $G_2$ is open, $\exists \epsilon_2 > 0$ such that $V_{\epsilon_2}(x_2) \subseteq G_2$. In particular, you can take $\epsilon_2 > 0 $ such that $V_{\epsilon_2}(x_2) \subseteq I_1$.Define $I_2 = [x_2 - \frac{\epsilon_2}{2}, x_2 + \frac{\epsilon_2}{2}]$ \ In general, because $F_n$ has no nonempty open intervals, $\exists x_n \in I_{n-1}$ such that $x_n \in G_n$. Because $G_n$ is open, $\exists \epsilon_n > 0$ such that $V_{\epsilon_n}(x_n) \subseteq G_n$. In particular, you can take $\epsilon_n > 0$ such that $V_{\epsilon_n}(x_n) \subseteq I_{n-1}$. Define $ I_n = [x_n - \frac{\epsilon_n}{2}, x_n + \frac{\epsilon_n}{2}] $.
Hence , we constructed a sequence of Nested Close Intervals $ I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq $... 
By the Nested Interval Theorem, $ \bigcap_n^{\infty} I_n \neq \emptyset $. Because $ I_n \subset V_{\epsilon_n}(x_n) \subseteq G_n$, we have $\bigcap_n^{\infty} G_n \neq \emptyset $.
Then, taking the complement: 
$(\bigcap_n^{\infty} G_n)^c = \bigcup_n^{\infty} F_n \neq \mathbb{R}$